# Check correctness of brackets in file with stack + error detection

Tags: java, strings, programming-challenge, stack

Task:

[image: Task:]

[image: Example of output:]

My implementation:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "Brackets.txt";
        Path filein = Paths.get(fileName);
        ParentStack s = new ParentStack();
        if (!Files.exists(filein)     ||
            !Files.isReadable(filein) ||
             Files.isDirectory(filein)) {
            System.err.println("Invalid input file !!!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(filein);){
            String line;
            char[] arrLineChar = null;
            char expected;
            int lineNumber = 0;
            boolean error = false;
     read: while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                 int charNumber = 0;
                 lineNumber++;
                 arrLineChar = line.toCharArray();
                 for (char lineChar : arrLineChar) {
                    charNumber++;
                    if(lineChar == '(' || lineChar == '{' || lineChar == '['){
                        s.push(lineChar);
                    }
                    if(lineChar == ')'){
                        if((expected = s.pop()) == lineChar-1){

                        }else{
                            System.out.println(line);
                            for (int j = 0; j < charNumber-1; j++) {
                                System.out.print(" ");
                            }
                            if(expected == '(')expected +=1;
                            else expected+=2;
                            System.out.println("^");
                            System.out.println("ERROR in line " + lineNumber + ".  " + lineChar
                                    + " found, but "+ (expected) + " expected.");
                            error = true;
                            break read;

                        }
                    }
                    if(lineChar == '}'){
                        if((expected = s.pop()) == lineChar-2){

                        }else{
                            System.out.println(line);
                            for (int j = 0; j < charNumber-1; j++) {
                                System.out.print(" ");
                            }
                            if(expected == '(')expected +=1;
                            else expected+=2;
                            System.out.println("^");
                            System.out.println("ERROR in line " + lineNumber + ".  " + lineChar
                                    + " found, but "+ (expected) + " expected.");
                            error = true;
                            break read;
                        }
                    }
                    if(lineChar == ']'){
                        if((expected = s.pop()) == lineChar-2){

                        }else{
                            System.out.println(line);
                            for (int j = 0; j < charNumber-1; j++) {
                                System.out.print(" ");
                            }
                            if(expected == '(')expected +=1;
                            else expected+=2;
                            System.out.println("^");
                            System.out.println("ERROR in line " + lineNumber + ".  " + lineChar
                                    + " found, but "+ (expected) + " expected.");
                            error = true;
                            break read;
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
            if(error == false)System.out.println("OK");


        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException");
            System.exit(1);
        }catch(ArithmeticException  e) {
            System.err.println("ArithmeticException");
            System.exit(1);
        }catch(NumberFormatException  e) {
            System.err.println("NumberFormatException");
            System.exit(1);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("Error");
        }
    }

}

public class ParentStack {
    private Node top;

    public void push(char p){
        top = new Node(p, top);
    }
    public char pop(){
        char buf = top.getVal(); 
        top = top.getNext();
        return buf; 
    }
    public boolean empty(){
        return top == null;
    }
}

public class Node {
    private char val;
    private Node next;

    public char getVal() {
        return val;
    }
    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public Node(char val, Node next){
        this.val=val;
        this.next=next;
    }
}

Bracets.txt

Warsaw(){
London[xxxx} ( 
Madrid Paris)}
Berlin
```

I realise that this is awful but it's what i can come up right now that is actually working. I tried [other way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399369/how-to-put-method-in-map) but my knowledge is not enough to do it. So what can i do better so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Implementation

You don't need to catch anything other than `IOException`. You're not doing math, you're not formatting numbers, and you should virtually never catch `Exception`.

It's often a good idea to print stack trace when logging an exception, so that you know what line the problem was on.

When checking a boolean, `if (!error)` is preferable to `if (error == false)`

Your file readability checks at the top are superfluous. Those cases will all result in an `IOException`. The specific type of `IOException` you get will tell you what went wrong.

Using labels in java is generally regarded very poorly. I would highly encourage you to avoid using them wherever possible.

Typically, solutions to this problem employ a `Map<Character, Character>`, where keys are opening brackets and values are closing brackets. This has several advantages. You can check if a character is an open bracket with `map.containsKey()`. You can check if a character is a closing bracket with `map.containsValue()`. You can look up the expected value with `map.get(openBracket)`. This lets you avoid duplicating your logic three times. Duplicate code is usually a mistake, and you should strive to avoid it without good reason.

You should look into `String.format(String, Object...)`. It's a powerful way to inject variables into a string while keeping it easy to read.

Deep nesting is hard to read, and should be avoided. You can design your loops and conditionals to end early with `continue` and `return`.

Try to use descriptive names that are not abbreviations. This makes code easier to read and understand without guesswork, especially for non-native speakers.

It's generally a bad idea to do a lot of work in the `main()` method, because it's procedural, not object-oriented. In this case, you're really only writing one procedure, so it's not awful, but as designed this work is not reusable by other code. It would be preferable to have a method which does the work, and have main call that method.

If you take all these things into consideration, your class might look more like:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public final class Main {

    private static final Map<Character, Character> BRACKETS = buildBracketMap();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final String fileName = "Brackets.txt";
        final Path filein = Paths.get(fileName);
        final ParentStack openBrackets = new ParentStack();

        try (final BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(filein, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) {
            String line;
            int lineNumber = 0;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                lineNumber++;
                final char[] characters = line.toCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
                    final char character = characters[i];
                    if (BRACKETS.containsKey(character)) {
                        openBrackets.push(character);
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (!BRACKETS.containsValue(character)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    final char currentOpenBracket = openBrackets.pop();
                    final char expectedCloseBracket = BRACKETS.get(currentOpenBracket);
                    if (character == expectedCloseBracket) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    System.out.println(line);
                    System.out.println(String.format("%" + (i + 1) + "s", "^"));
                    System.out.println(
                            String.format("ERROR in line %d. '%c' found, but '%c' expected.",
                                    lineNumber, character, expectedCloseBracket));
                    return;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("OK");
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private static final Map<Character, Character> buildBracketMap() {
        final Map<Character, Character> bracketMap = new HashMap<>(3);
        bracketMap.put('(', ')');
        bracketMap.put('{', '}');
        bracketMap.put('[', ']');
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(bracketMap);
    }

}
```